# HTML5 Videos crashing System UI

Tags: video, system-error, html5

I was watching videos on m.youtube.com and got this System UI error. Video kept playing, until I pressed ok and everything crashed and 5 seconds later i see the lock screen. I unlock with my fingerprint and anytime I put play it does the same. I tryed other videos and the same thing happens, restart fixed for 5 mintues then I re got the glitch and any other html5 video doesn't work anymore. Also sometimes the home, back and recent apps button and the top bars disappear after this glitch before the screen going black etc. Youtube app works fine though...

P.S. This happened on a Wiko UFEEL Prime running the latest update (6.0.1 [21]) I don't think it can be the hardware because I have 4GB of RAM and a 1.3GhZ octa-core processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix: also if @Geert-Jan Graulus is correct i would let it be a last resort as i keep lots of important stuff on my phone.

My fix: download another browser, like firefox, dolphin, etc. this worked for me. chrome sucks anyway

Comment: "i keep lots of important stuff on my phone" but you have backups, right? If you don't have backups, it can't have been that important.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the exact same problem on my UFeelPrime...

Returning to factory settings without copying files from my back-up solved the issue in my case. However, it reappears as soon as you update Google play services. The problem must thus lie in the latest update of the latter OR one of the apps updated by play services.

I have not found a more permanent solution yet, but for now a hard reset and not updating Google play services is a valid solution.

Update: the problem lies in chrome for android itself: simply removing the updates and returning the chrome app to factory settings will do the trick untill a more permanent solution is found.

Comment: I found a solution for myself: when watching online videos i now use firefox, that seemed to solve the issue for me